# Проблема с обновлением PHP на MacOS

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. Работаю с проектом Laravel, но он написан с версией PHP8, а у меня установлена PHP7. Попытался обновить PHP через:
`brew install php`, но получил ошибку:

```
Error: php: Failed to download resource "freetds"
Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed for: https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.3.9.tar.gz
```

Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным и может подсказать, как решить эту проблему? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сделать буквально то, что от у вас просят в ошибке - установить curl:

```
brew install curl
```

после этого ошибка должна уйти

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Получилось скачать curl, но при установке возникла другая ошибка: `Error: php: Failed to download resource "sqlite"`. Можете подсказать с этим?

Comment: @ТимурКовалев, аналогично установите sqlite ) Вообще, скорей всего чуть выше чем эта ошибка должно быть указано и предупреждение,  гладящее о том, почему зависимости вроде curl и sqlite не были установлены автоматически

Comment: Спасибо, установить PHP получилось. Теперь папка находится по адресу /usr/local/etc/php/8.1. Но в терминале ещё установлена старая версия, и когда ввожу команду `php -v` получаю ответ `PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2019 20:50:16) ( NTS )`. Так вот, как мне сделать так, чтобы в терминале у меня была версия, которую я установил?

Comment: @ТимурКовалев, замените симлинки на новую версию - `brew link --override php@8.1.2`(ну или другую установленную версию из 8.x, если ставили из какого-нибудь tap-а).. ну и если не нужна старая версия, то ее можно удалить(`brew uninstall php@7.3.8`)